# How to count the number each distinct value appears in a column

Tags: r

adding on to my initial question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013908/create-a-new-column-that-only-shows-the-winning-team) :

I am trying to count the amount of (wins) each country has. So I used a pipeline from my dataframe that allows me to find the amount of distinct teams that won, **now I am trying to count the amount of times each distinct team has won**. I'm at this point now.

#

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

results <- intl.football.results
results1 <- results[ , c("home_team","away_team","home_score","away_score")]
results10 <- results[1:10, c("home_team","away_team","home_score","away_score")]

results1$who_wins <- with(results1,
                       ifelse(home_score > away_score, results10$home_team,
                              ifelse(home_score < away_score, results$away_team, 0)))

final <- results1$who_wins
finaldeck <- data.frame(results1)

finaldeck %>%
  group_by(who_wins) %>% distinct(who_wins)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to count the number of distinct elements, use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
finaldeck %>%         
     count(who_wins)
```

Comment: hi @akrun, i think i have to rephrase my question a bit. What you typed above tells me the amount of distinct values (286), I want to know is many times each of these (286) values has appeared in a larger df. Can I use the count() function?

Comment: @adwang31  If that is the case, you need `count` I though you want to have number of distinct elements

Answer (score 0):

In base R, one would use `table` for that:

```
finaldeck <- data.frame(who_wins = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 1000, replace = TRUE))
table(finaldeck$who_wins)
```